# Rails and Heroku - Rake db:seed only populates some databases and not others?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, seed

I have a rails app that I've been working on locally and have deployed to heroku. I have a lot of data that needs to be seeded that has worked well locally, with a small issue that I didn't pay much mind to. Basically I have a number of tables covering:

- Feature,
- Addon,
- Budget,
- ProjectType
- Industry

etc.

When I create/reset the local database and run the `rake db:seed` it seeds perfectly to each database.

However, as its a WIP I keep adding new tables and running the seed rake db:seed, and noticed that where it should have been doubling up all of the seeded data (because I never cleared the data), it actually only duplicated this info on the Addon, and Feature tables. The other tables were unchanged. I thought nothing of it, until I started trying to run heroku run rake db:seed to populate my production database and noticed that in the logs it was also only populating the Addon and Feature tables, and skipping over the rest.

An extract from some of my seed file (I've shortened with ... as they are very repetitive but all the same):

```
#Populate the features table
Feature.destroy_all

Feature.create(id: 1, name: 'Contact form')
Feature.create(id: 2, name: 'Blog')
Feature.create(id: 3, name: 'Mailing list signup')
...
...

#Populate the addons table
Addon.destroy_all

Addon.create(id: 1, name: 'Domain registration')
Addon.create(id: 2, name: 'Hosting')
Addon.create(id: 3, name: 'Create content')
...
...

#Populating the industries table
Industry.destroy_all

Industry.create(id: 1, name: 'Accounting')
Industry.create(id: 2, name: 'Airlines')
Industry.create(id: 3, name: 'Alternative Medicine')
...
...

# Populating the budgets table
Budget.destroy_all

Budget.create(id: 1, name: 'Micro', minimum: 250, maximum: 1000)
Budget.create(id: 2, name: 'Simple', minimum: 1000, maximum: 2500)
...
...
```

I noticed that when I try populate the heroku database with heroku run rake db:seed the data all seems to "rollback". Here is an extract from the console:

First I run `heroku run rake db:migrate`

```
    D, [2016-09-01T12:24:31.463009 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.8ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(4467995963834188590);
    D, [2016-09-01T12:24:31.476939 #3] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
    D, [2016-09-01T12:24:31.507280 #3] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", :environment], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    D, [2016-09-01T12:24:31.518500 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  BEGIN
    D, [2016-09-01T12:24:31.522494 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  COMMIT
    D, [2016-09-01T12:24:31.524504 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.8ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(4467995963834188590)
```

Then I run rake `heroku run rake db:seed`

For the tables where it doesn't work it seems to do this:

```
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.229540 #3] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.261528 #3] DEBUG -- :   Budget Load (2.3ms)  SELECT "budgets".* FROM "budgets"
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.293954 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.320090 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.9ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.322421 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.325418 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.8ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.327617 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.331031 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.8ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.333423 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.8ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.338379 #3] DEBUG -- :    (2.5ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.340601 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.344061 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.346208 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.349342 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.8ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.353205 #3] DEBUG -- :    (3.4ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.358254 #3] DEBUG -- :    (2.5ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.360392 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.363406 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.8ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.365488 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.6ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.367862 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.369869 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.372657 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.8ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.378093 #3] DEBUG -- :   Industry Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "industries".* FROM "industries"
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.393455 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.8ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.409125 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.411280 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.6ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.414223 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.6ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.416244 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.419335 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.421511 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.425412 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.427570 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.431136 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.433536 #3] DEBUG -- :    (2.0ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.438208 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:28.440437 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  BEGIN
```

And then when it passes over the features and addons, it seems to work fine:

```
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:29.506570 #3] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.9ms)  INSERT INTO "features" ("id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["id", 1], ["name", "Contact form"], ["created_at", 2016-09-01 12:27:29 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-09-01 12:27:29 UTC]]
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:29.509515 #3] DEBUG -- :    (2.5ms)  COMMIT
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:29.512944 #3] DEBUG -- :    (2.2ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:29.516551 #3] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.9ms)  INSERT INTO "features" ("id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["id", 2], ["name", "Blog"], ["created_at", 2016-09-01 12:27:29 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-09-01 12:27:29 UTC]]
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:29.519489 #3] DEBUG -- :    (2.5ms)  COMMIT
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:29.522216 #3] DEBUG -- :    (2.5ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-09-01T12:27:29.526125 #3] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.9ms)  INSERT INTO "features" ("id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["id", 3], ["name", "Mailing list signup"], ["created_at", 2016-09-01 12:27:29 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-09-01 12:27:29 UTC]]
```

I did notice that of the tables, Addons and Features both have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association with other tables while the rest of the tables that aren't working have a `belongs_to` association with some other tables. Not sure if that is just a coincidence? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok from what I can tell this appears to be an issue with seeding databases of `belongs_to` models. I worked around this by:

Going into each model and `#`'ing the `belongs_to` relationship. I then repushed with:

```
git add .
git commit -m "hashed belongs_to associations"
git push
git push heroku master
heroku run rake db:seed
```

When I checked the database, it's seems to be perfect now. I will now unhash the relationships, re git and re push to heroku.

Comment: I had the same problem, and inexplicably, commenting out the belongs_to relationships works.  This is a bug, no?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try using find_or_create_by! method which will first check if the record exist and only create if it does not exist.:

```
Feature.find_or_create_by!(name: 'Contact form')
```

Also it will take care of validation when you use the bang sign at the end of the method. you also do not have to mention the id here. As you are providing the id, that might be creating an issue for you.

Let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: This seems to deal with the symptoms without addressing the underlying issue at all.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it didn't work. Seems to be an issue with the belongs_to relationships. Posted my work around as the answer above.

Comment: may I know which version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Since Rails 5.1 belongs_to-associated objects are required by default (see https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html). Maybe some of the belongs_to-associations of your seeded models are not existing, that's why heroku won’t seed the models since presence-validation fails.

One easy solution is to flag the associations as optional:

```rb
class Budget 
   belongs_to :feature, optional: true
   ....
end
```